# Pros and cons of database choice for OwnCloud

Tags: database, postgresql, mariadb, owncloud

OwnCloud provides 3 choices for its database:

- SQLite
- MariaDB
- PostgreSQL

Obviously SQLite is not a practical choice, since it can rarely handle the load. What about the other two? Is MariaDB or PostgreSQL clearly superior? Do they both have their niche uses, and if so, what are the key points to consider when deciding which one to use?

To be clear, I am asking only about use of a database in conjunction with OwnCloud.

Comment: This is closed as opinion-based, but the top answer gives a factual, referenced source. Based on specific expertise.

Answer (score 3):

The [OwnCloud performance tuning documentation](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/performance_tuning.html) recommends using MySQL/MariaDB.

There are some people using PostgreSQL, including some core developers, but your installation will be more prone to errors and various problems if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

I run a fairly large owncloud install (company) and recommend MariaDB since its MySQL, which is basically the defacto standard for relational databases for many many many years across many many many applications.

Unless you are doing something INSANE with owncloud, MariaDB will never be the performance limiting factor. And even if it was, you can size it appropriately and do standard performance tuning.

Owncloud docs themself recommend MariaDB.